# Retrieving Regex matched pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to retrieve a regex pattern matched strings from the given input.

Lets say, the pattern I need to get is like,

```
"http://mysite.com/<somerandomvalues>/images/<againsomerandomvalues>.jpg"
```

Now I created the following regex pattern for  this,

```
http:\/\/.*\.mysite\.com\/.*\/images\/.*\.jpg
```

Can anybody illustrate how to retrieve all the matched pattern with this regx expression using Java?

Comment: if you make an SSCCE you might solve your own problem in the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mask slashes but literal dots:

```
    String regex = "http://(.*)\\.mysite\\.com/(.*)/images/(.*)\\.jpg";
    String   url = "http://www.mysite.com/work/images/cat.jpg";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher (url);

    if (matcher.matches ())
    {
        int n = matcher.groupCount ();
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
            System.out.println (matcher.group (i));
    }
```

Result:

```
www
work
cat
```

Answer (score 2):

Some simple Java example:

```
String my_regex = "http://.*.mysite.com/.*/images/.*.jpg";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(my_regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string_to_be_matched);
// Check all occurance
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but I am getting "illegal escape character" error

Comment: probably because of the "\", i have tested the regex in java it was just a proof of concept. Let me edit it with the right escape sequence.

Comment: You have to mask the dots, to prevent them from matching every character. (omysite, xjpg)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is not clear if you want the whole matching string or only the groups.

[Bogdan Emil Mariesan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817497/retrieving-regex-matched-pattern#9817569) can be reduced to

```java
if ( matcher.matches () ) System.out.println(string_to_be_matched);
```

because you know it is mathed and there are no groups.

IMHO, [user unknown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817497/retrieving-regex-matched-pattern#9817939) is correct if you want to get matched groups.

I just want to add additional information (for others) that if you need matched group you can use `replaceFirst()` method too:

```java
String firstGroup = string.replaceFirst( "http://mysite.com/(.*)/images/", "$1" );
```

**But** performance of Pattern.compile approach if better if there are two or more groups or if you need to do that multiple times (on the other hand in programming contests, for example, it is faster to write `replaceFirst()`).